# I can't set a default value on hook_form_alter()

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I have form alter for the `user_register_form` which is called.
In this hook, I try to set a default value for a textfield but it doesn't work.
I've tried all the syntax possible `#default_value`, `#value`, `value`, `default_value`, event in the attributes array.

This is my code.

```
function pre_registration_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_code_postal']['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
  $form['field_code_postal']['#default_value'] = 'COUCOU';
  $form['field_code_postal']['#value'] = 'COUCOU';
  $form['field_code_postal']['value'] = 'COUCOU';
  $form['field_code_postal']['value']['#value'] = 'COUCOU';
  $form['field_code_postal']['value']['#default_value'] = 'COUCOU';
  $form['field_code_postal']['value']['value'] = 'COUCOU';
  $form['field_code_postal']['value']['default_value'] = 'COUCOU';
  $form['field_code_postal']['default_value'] = 'COUCOU';

  $form['field_code_postal']['#attributes']['value'] = 'COUCOU1';
  $form['field_code_postal']['#attributes']['#value'] = 'COUCOU2';
  $form['field_code_postal']['#attributes']['default_value'] = 'COUCOU3';
  $form['field_code_postal']['#attributes']['#default_value'] = 'COUCOU4';
}
```

How can I set a default value?

Comment: $form['field_code_postal'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#default_value']

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't work, FYI I'm using D8 not D7.

Answer (score 11):

According to the documentation for [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) you can use code similar to the following one.

```php
 $form['field_code_postal']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] ='COUCOU1';
```

If you want to, for example, fill an entity referenced field, you can use the following code.

```php
$form['field_image']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value'] = $file;
```

Comment: For future readers, the documentation for `hook_form_alter()` does not describe the structure of a form containing entity fields. The description of the form structure used for an entity field is given in the documentation for that field type.

Answer (score 2):

For my case, I wanted a default automatic node title for a custom content type.

In `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, I added a line containing `kint($form['title']);` which allowed me to see the array structure for the node title field. Then, I changed the default value for the node title with the following code.

```php
$form['title']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 'my custom node title';`
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the default value in `hook_form_alter()`, make a dump of `$form`. You will see the array structure and what you need to target.

In my case with a webform form, actually I can do this.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'form_submission_lorem_add_form') {
    if (isset($form['elements']['nom'])) {
      $form['elements']['nom']['#default_value'] = 'hello world!';
    }
  }
}
```

The form markup then includes the following lines.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

**In Drupal 8:**

```
$form['field_name']['widget']['#default_value'][0] = 'value';
```